# Developing SBT plugin with Dispatch 0.11.0 results in Scala compiler's mysterious errors

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-dispatch

I'm new to Scala and Dispatch, and I can't seem to get a basic Post request working.

I'm actually building a sbt plugin that uploads files to a third party service.

Here is my `build.sbt` file:

```
sbtPlugin := true

name := "sbt-sweet-plugin"

organization := "com.mattwalters"

version := "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies += "net.databinder.dispatch" %% "dispatch-core" % "0.11.0"
```

And here is the plugin's `SweetPlugin.scala`:

```
package com.mattwalters

import sbt._
import Keys._
import dispatch._

object SweetPlugin extends Plugin {

  import SweetKeys._
  object SweetKeys {

    lazy val sweetApiToken = 
      SettingKey[String]("Required. Find yours at https://example.com/account/#api")
    lazy val someOtherToken = 
      SettingKey[String]("Required. Find yours at https://example.com/some/other/token/")
    lazy val sweetFile = 
      SettingKey[String]("Required. File data")
    lazy val sweetotes = 
      SettingKey[String]("Required. Release notes")

    lazy val sweetUpload = 
      TaskKey[Unit]("sweetUpload", "A task to upload the specified sweet file.")
  }

  override lazy val settings = Seq (
    sweetNotes := "some default notes",
    // define the upload task
    sweetUpload <<= (
      sweetApiToken,
      someOtherToken,
      sweetFile,
      sweetNotes
    ) map { (
      sweetApiToken,
      someOtherToken,
      sweetFile,
      sweetNotes
    ) =>
      // define http stuff here 
      val request = :/("www.example.com") / "some" / "random" / "endpoint" 
      val post = request.POST
      post.addParameter("api_token", sweetApiToken)
      post.addParameter("some_other_token", someOtherToken)
      post.addParameter("file", io.Source.fromFile(sweetFile).mkString)
      post.addParameter("notes", sweetNotes)
      val responseFuture = Http(post OK as.String)
      val response = responseFuture()
      println(response) // see if we can get something at all....
    }
  )
}
```

The dispatch documentation shows:

```
import dispatch._, Defaults._
```

but I get

```
reference to Defaults is ambiguous;
[error] it is imported twice in the same scope by
```

removing `, Defaults._` makes this error go away.

I also tried the recommendation from [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dispatch-scala/HnOZoVWa8Gs):

```
import dispatch._
Import dispatch.Default._
```

But alas I get:

```
object Default is not a member of package dispatch
[error] import dispatch.Default._
```

Also tried the advice from 
[Passing implicit ExecutionContext to contained objects/called methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17849749/passing-implicit-executioncontext-to-contained-objects-called-methods):

```
import concurrent._
import concurrent.duration._
```

But I still get

```
Cannot find an implicit ExecutionContext, either require one yourself or import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
```

Back to square one...

New to scala so any advice at all on the code above is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the recommended `sbt console` run works fine, it looks like **one of your other imports also has a `Defaults` module**. It's a standard approach in Scala for collecting [implicit values to be used as function params](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/implicit-parameters.html) (another naming convention is `Implicits`).

The other problem is that there is a typo/out-of-date problem in the import statement you got from Google Groups - it's `Defaults`, plural.

**In summary - the best solution is to explicitly let Scala know which module you want to use:**

```
import dispatch._
import dispatch.Defaults._
```

---

In the general case, **only if the library's docs don't say otherwise**: the last error message is pretty common to concurrent programming in Scala. To quote the relevant part:

> either require one yourself or import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

So, unless you want to roll your own `ExecutionContext`, just import the `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` one via the `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits` module.

Comment: I've added 'import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global' but I get the error: 'not found: object ExecutionContext'. Any ideas?

Comment: @mattwalters: and please see the edit again. Sorry about the somewhat chaotic response.

Comment: By the way, when you say "just had a look at the package through sbt". Where exactly did you look...?

Comment: @mattwalters : thanks, but I'd have more belief in my supernatural abilities if the reply wasn't so messy - the facts that I was in a hurry and you didn't get an answer for a long time is not a mitigating circumstance for me ;). Regardless, if you've missed it, take a look at the final edits - I've added an explanation of the core reason of the error, that (and the provided link) will be certainly useful for you in the future. Regarding "taking a look" - in this case it was shorthand for "running sbt", but generally if there's no doc available you can download such a project and run `sbt doc`.